# Excel DateTime To Date #VALUE! error using =INT()

Tags: excel

[image]

Hey,

so I have a column on the left sample_datetime and a column on the right sample_date where i used "=INT(cell to the left)" to get the date only. but it is not getting a value when the date time format changes. and I'm not sure why this is?  ive tried changed the format of the cell (datetime) that doesnt turn out a date value to the same format as the one that does but the cell doesnt change.

any ideas on what i can do? and the reason why it doesnt work

01/12/2010  12:30:00 PM

this is what the one that gets a date value looks like in the function bar 
the format of the cell is dd/mm/yyyy h:mm

1/13/1994 11:00:00

this is what the one that does not get a date value looks like in the function bar
the format of the cell is general

Comment: Please don't SHOUT WHEN ASKING YOUR QUESTIONS. It won't get you help faster, and it makes the subject harder for people to read. (Plus, it's really annoying, and means someone always has to edit your question to remove the CAPS.) Thanks.

Comment: @KenWhite o sry i never knew that was a problem thats acutally how i title most my files and stuff so i just do that without thinking for emails and subjects too ill remember not to do that again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have your system date format set to "dd/mm/yyyy". The date "01/12/2010" is "first of December" & "1/13/1994" is "first of thirteenth month" which doesn't make sense.

You either have to change your date format - which doesn't sound right - or you need to break apart the date using "mid", "left", "right", etc and build the date using "Date(year, month, day)" function.

Comment: wow thank you enigmativity i didnt even notice that the dates and times wouldnt make sense.  I will work on it right away thanks

Comment: @Chaostryder if you pasted the data into the worksheet, you should try changing the format and then re-pasting the data.  That way you won't have to use the MID/LEFT/RIGHT approach.

Answer (score 2):

The values that are working are on the right, which means they are numbers/dates. The ones that are not working are on the left, which means they are text entries. Change them to date/time entries by formatting as such. If that doesn't work let me know and I'll think of other possibilities.