# Excel #Value error when using DATEVALUE function

Tags: excel, date, datetime

In cell `A2` I have `7/21/2014 12:44:36 PM`

When I use `DATEVALUE(LEFT(A2;FIND(" ";A2)-1))` I get the error `#VALUE`.

When I use `LEFT(A2;FIND(" ";A2)-1)` I get `7/21/2014`.

What do I need do that function `DATEVALUE(LEFT(A2;FIND(" ";A2)-1))` to return just the date?

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me, especially "Whar need do that function". What are you hoping to return?

Comment: Please format the code in your post and try to phrase an actual question. Are you trying to fix a broken function? What is your actual goal?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`DATEVALUE()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/datevalue-HP005209044.aspx) is designed to make a `Date` out of plain text. Your cell is currently a `Date/Time`, which is a numeric value. I recommend using one of the following solutions to get the date from the cell.

#### Using [`DATE()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/date-function-HP010062283.aspx)

---

This is the cleanest option and the method that I would recommend.

```
=DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2),DAY(A2))
```

[`YEAR()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/year-function-HP010343045.aspx) gets the `Year` value from the cell, [`MONTH()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/month-function-HP010062291.aspx) gets the `Month` value, and [`DAY()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/day-function-HP010062285.aspx) gets the `Day` value. The [`DATE()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/date-function-HP010062283.aspx) function takes a `Year`, `Month`, and `Day` value, so by passing them into [`DATE()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/date-function-HP010062283.aspx) we can get the `Date` value from `A2`.

#### Using [`INT()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/int-function-HP010062437.aspx)

---

If we look at the numeric value of your `Date` in `A2`, we see that it is `41841.5309722222`. The whole portion of the number (`41841.`) is the date and the decimal portion (`.5309722222`) is the time. So if we take `INT(A2)` to convert this value to an integer, we will lose the decimal portion so that all that remains (`41841`) is the date. So this is our formula for using [`INT()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/int-function-HP010062437.aspx)

```
=INT(A2)
```

The same idea can be accomplished with [`ROUNDDOWN(A2,0)`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/rounddown-HP005209241.aspx) or [`=FLOOR.MATH(A2)`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/floor-math-function-HA102753279.aspx) or [`=FLOOR(A2,1)`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/floor-HP005209094.aspx).

#### Using [`DATEVALUE()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/datevalue-HP005209044.aspx)

---

While the first solution is the cleanest, there is a way to do this with [`DATEVALUE()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/datevalue-HP005209044.aspx) that involves converting the cell into `Text` first. The [`TEXT()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/text-function-HP010062580.aspx) function takes a value and a format string, so we format the cell value as `Text` as follows

```
=TEXT(A2,"yyyy-mm-dd")
```

And this gives us

```
2014-07-21
```

We then pass that result into [`DATEVALUE()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/datevalue-HP005209044.aspx)

```
=DATEVALUE(TEXT(A2,"yyyy-mm-dd"))
```

You will need to format the result as a date.

#### Using [`LEFT()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/left-leftb-functions-HP005209153.aspx) and [`DATEVALUE()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/datevalue-HP005209044.aspx)

---

Based on [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219657/excel-datetime-to-date-value-error-using-int) that I found, it appears the issue **could** be a result of inconsistent formatting, so you might try this solution

```
=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A2,FIND(" ",A2)-1))
```

I have included my results with this and the other methods in a screenshot below. You can see by my use of the [`TYPE()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/type-function-HP010062400.aspx) command below the value that I tested this on both a `number` and `text`.

#### Results

[image: Results of formulas on different value types]

#### Formatting

---

I'm assuming you want just the date for calculation purposes, but if you just want to display the date, you can [format the cell to only show the date and ignore the time element](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/format-a-date-the-way-you-want-HA102809474.aspx) although the time element will still be present in the cell. I'm assuming you know about this, but since you didn't specify, it is a possible solution.

Comment: @pnuts, 1) His original function works on a string, I've tried it. The only way he would have gotten the `#VALUE` error is if he was trying to use `DATEVALUE()` on a numerical value, so I'm assuming it's numerical. Also, most of my solutions work with a string anyways (including my recommended one) so it doesn't matter. 2) Yes, I see the region specific issue, but he should be able to substitute a `,` for a `;` without too much difficulty. I want people to understand my solution, not just copy-paste it.

Comment: When use =DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2),DAY(A2)) return #VALUE!; =INT(A2) return #VALUE!; =TEXT(A2;"yyyy-mm-dd") return 7/21/2014 12:44:36 PM. Format cell A2 is General, when chage to Date format nothing happens and functions return same error value

Comment: You missed the second part of the `TEXT()` solution. Did you try the full `=DATEVALUE(TEXT(A2,"yyyy-mm-dd"))`?

Comment: I've tried all of my solutions on both text and numbers and they work fine. Did you forget to substitue `;` in the `INT()` and `DATE()` solutions?

Comment: @Sashka, try to format your questions and comments with the appropriate code blocks. Use the ` character in questions and comments or you can use 4 spaces in your questions if you're formatting multiple lines of code in a block by themselves. That will help us all out. Thanks! :-)

Comment: @Sashka, sorry for the excessive comments, I will clean them up once we figure this out, but I wanted to let you know that I've added another solution that references a different StackOverflow post that might apply here. See if that helps.

Comment: @Sashka, I've added results. Let me know if anything is clicking for you. You might try using the `TYPE()` function to help us get this all cleared up.

Answer (score 2):

Please try:

```
 =INT(A2)
```

and format the result to suit.

In a comment I have just seen you mention "=INT(A2) return #VALUE!" so I would suggest selecting your date cells, DATA > Data Tools, - Text to Columns, Delimited, Delimiters Tab (only), and at Step 3 of 3 choose MDY for Date: or change your locale to say USA.

If neither work try =INT(TRIM(A2)) in case you have leading spaces (though not showing them).

If still not working, try applying [`=CLEAN`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/clean-function-HP010062560.aspx).

If still nothing works then some further details of where your dates are coming from and how imported would be helpful, and of your locale and default date format.

Answer (score 1):

**SIMPLE SOLUTION - I found a solve that worked very well:**

```
=DATEVALUE(TEXT([CELL],"MM/DD/YYYY")
```

Effectively this lets me convert any value into text, then back into date. It fixed my Datevalue error and I can use it regardless of the original cell formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Date macros are depending on the system date format and based on configured system date format the macros can fail to work. Try below solution. We faced similar issue after open excel file sent by me on another laptop where system date/time format was different. On destination laptop formulas using date functions started giving error. After following below steps errors disappeared.

Left click on bottom right portion of task bar where time is displayed
Click on date and time settings
Click on change date and time
Change calendar settings
Click on reset to go back to original values
Click on OK on all opened dialogues
Now excel formula error should disappear