# converting 2/17/2013 10:37 AM to date format "MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS" excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a field in excel "Access date" I am trying to convert a text cell "2/17/2013 10:37 AM" when I try and use =text(A2,"MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS") it returns the same value as I put in instead of 02/17/2013  10:37:00

Could anyone please advise?

Comment: Is the cell you're trying to convert really date or just text? If you change its format to Numeric, what does it look like?

Comment: It works on libre office even when I try to break it by changing the format of the original cell to eg text or numeric. I suggest you check the format of the cell

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel #Value error when using DATEVALUE function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24937847/excel-value-error-when-using-datevalue-function)

Comment: Try using the [`TYPE()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TYPE-function-45b4e688-4bc3-48b3-a105-ffa892995899) function to determine what the actual value is in the cell, i.e. value, text, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I think that Excel cannot recognize the date as you are in a country which does not support the mm/dd/yyyy format (e.g. European countries). Excel considers the value as text only.

The only way I know to convert it in date is to extract every piece of information in this text, using Excel text function. For example, given the value that you provide, you can try (assuming your value is in "A1"):

```
=DATE(VALUE(MID(A1;SEARCH("/";A1;SEARCH("/";A1)+1)+1;4));
LEFT(A1;SEARCH("/";A1)-1);
MID(A1;SEARCH("/";A1)+1;SEARCH("/";A1;SEARCH("/";A1)+1)-SEARCH("/";A1)-1))
+TIME(VALUE(MID(A1;SEARCH(" ";A1);SEARCH(":";A1)-SEARCH(" ";A1)))+IF(RIGHT(A1;2)="AM";0;12);
VALUE(MID(A1;SEARCH(":";A1)+1;2));
0)
```

That is quite a long formula... but the only way I can think of using Excel (should be a lot easier with R for example). This formula takes the assumptions that the year value is always 4 characters long, and that the minutes value is always 2 characters long.

If you want to convert it, you can then use TEXT function (or directly insert it in the previous formula) to transform your date in a text value (which is a bit odd). As I am working in France, the formula I need to use is the following (assuming I insert the first formula in "B1") :

```
=TEXT(B1;"mm/jj/aaaa hh:mm")
```

Note : in France "j" stand for "d" (days) and "a" stands for "y" (years)

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

Try converting the text representation of date you have to value, which you can then format as a date:

```
=TEXT(VALUE(A2),"MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS")
```

Comment: When I try to use `=VALUE("2/17/2013 10:37 AM")` I get a `#VALUE` error. This also happens when I use my local date format `=VALUE("17/2/2013 10:37 AM")`. Did you test this answer?